# Codeigniter two param database breadcrumb

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

I am using the php framework codeigniter.

I am attempting to create a  here is an example:

- `animals/feline/lion`
- `animals/feline/tiger`
- `animals/feline/snow-leopard`
- `animals/canine/wolf`
- `animals/canine/coyote`

Where both `genus` (feline) and `species` (lion) are both retrieved from a database and `animals` is a controller. I have models that place `genus` and `species` in their respective arrays. I also wish to have views for each step along the breadcrumb as follows:

- `animals`
- `animals/feline`
- `animals/canine`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just looked at [autocrumb](https://bitbucket.org/ardinotow/autocrumb/overview) and all it was as for displaying the breadcrumb control structure on the view, and not what I want.

Comment: Are you asking for help finding a breadcrumb library that will let you set the breadcrumbs in the controller so you can set them for genus and species based on the results from the database?

Comment: Yes, however I don't think I need a library. The most basic way of achieving this is satisfactory.

Comment: Gotcha... Then I would try Damine Pirsy's solution. I think that's the best way to go about it.

Comment: At the moment Damine Pirsy's solution doesn't seam to accommodate for database interaction.

Comment: @ThomasReggi I updated my answer, see if this is closer to what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [URi routing.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), as another approach than `__remap()`, which is better, but I just wanted to give another choice

```
$route['animals/(:any)/(:any)'] = "animals/method/$1/$2";
```

In you animals controller you have

```
 function method($genus,$species)
 {

   $data['breadcrumb'] = 'animals -> '.$genus.' -> '.$species.
   $this->load->view('breadcrumb', $data);
   $this->load->view('animals/'.$genus.'/'.$species);
 }
```

view **breadcrumb.php**:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
<?php echo $breadcrumb;?>  <!-- Display: animals -> feline -> lion -->
</div>
```

**View folder** contains:

```
breadcrumb.php
animals /
          feline /
                   feline.php
          canine/  
                   wolf.php
```

Is this what you were looking for?

**EDIT after comments:**

SO looks like we've mistaken what you wanted. If you're retrieving those variables from DB, then you could do like this:

```
function index()
{
  $this->load->view('animals/index');
}

function genus($genus)
{
  $data['genus_data'] = $this->your_model->load_genus_data($genus);
  $this->load->view('animals/genus',$data);
}
function species($genus,$species)
{
 $data['genus_data'] = $this->your_model->load_genus_data($genus);
 $data['species_data'] = $this->your_model->load_species_data($species);
 $this->load->view('animal/genusspecies',$data);
}
```

In your view **genus.php** (in folder animal):

```
<?php $genus_data->name;?> is an animal that...Here's a pic in its habitat.
```

In your view **genusspecies.php** (in folder animal):

```
<?php $species_data->name;?> is a species of genus <?php $genus_data->name;?>....
```

all those might be html snippets you load from database;

Your routing might look like this then:

```
$route['animal'] = "animal";
$route['animal/(:any)'] = "animal/genus/$1";
$route['animal/(:any)/(:any)'] = "animal/species/$1/$2";
```

If I were you, I'll go about this way. Do I got it better or am I still wrong somewhere?

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but the main problem is database interaction. You are proposing that I have a view for both param $1 (genus) and param $2 (species) when these items are variables being retrieved from a database. I desire a specific template for animals (index method), animals/genus, and animals/genus/species. Meaning... the database can contain more "animals" (ie. animals/reptile, animals/reptile/snake) etc.

Comment: Well, actually, if you re-read your questions, looks like it's you who proposed that `I also wish to have views for each step along the breadcrumb as follows:

    animals
    animals/feline
    animals/canine
`, so I suggested accordingly. It's midnight here, thought, so I might have misunderstood

Comment: Thanks so much, most of this makes a lot of sense, and I think I am getting the hang of this now =] (second day with ci & mvc). Right now when I query a species the genus method is taking control. Any ideas?

Comment: What I meant about the views for each was that i didn't just want `animals/canine/wolf` I also wanted the landing pages for each breadcrumb. I can understand the confusion.

Comment: I just got it to work by reversing the order of the routes.`$route['animal/(:any)/(:any)'] = "animal/species/$1/$2";` then  `$route['animal/(:any)'] = "animal/genus/$1";`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `_remap()` function to your animals controller

```
if($this->uri->segment(3) === FALSE)
{
    $this->genus();
}
else
{
    $this->species();
}
```

This assumes you have a method called `genus()` and a method called `species()`

`_remap()` docs:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

URI Library docs:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('animals/' . $genus . '/' . $species);
```